# Storing Rectangles/Circles/Triangles in a KD-Tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, kdtree

I was looking at Kd-tree and found some implementations of this algorithm. All of these were storing points (2d in major of cases). What I am trying to achieve is to store different shapes in it like rectangle, triangle etc. **So is it possible in kd-trees to store shapes**? I have some code for Quad-trees. In that shapes were being stored.

Comment: What happens if a cut splits the shape in two? Where do you want to store the shape? The nice thing with points is that they cannot be cut.

Comment: I imagine you can modify a kd-tree to have additional leaves for the shapes. The non-leaf nodes will, as per usual, be points. How to determine these points could be a little complex and what to do with split shapes needs to be determined.

Comment: Have a look at r-trees instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not so different than the method used for Quad trees.

For each shape, you should be able to compute :

- its centroid.
- its envelope.

When computing the median, use the centroids. The envelope of a shape should fit in the quad. When inserting a shape in a quad, check if its envelope crosses the hyperplane. If true, store the shape in the quad. If false, put this shape in the appropriate list of shapes of your left or right quad 
construction call.

Cheers

Comment: How should I check that rectangle is going to be on the left side or right side?

Comment: The rectangle's envelope is caracterized by its xMin/xMax, yMin,yMax, zMin,zMax. You can compare these coordinates with hyperplane coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do with your set of shapes once you have your kd-tree for it.  Let's say you have a set of rectangles, and you want to quickly find all rectangles that are completely contained in a query rectangle.  Then the appropriate way to use a kd-tree (or better yet, a range tree imo) is to store the min and max x and y coordinates for the rectangle as a 4-dimensional point and build a tree for the 4-dimensional points.  Then, for a query rectangle (a0,a1)x(b0,b1), you use the tree to do a range query on the 4-dimensional points using the range (a0,+inf) x (-inf, a1) x (b0, +inf) x (-inf, b1).

Comment: I want to do exactly the same, I have some rectangles and I want to find rectangles inside a query rectangle. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30535/A-Simple-QuadTree-Implementation-in-C. This project does the same using quad-tree, but I want to do this in quadtree.

Comment: What do you mean by 4-dimentional. Do you mean to save 4 points in a kd-tree node. I am thinking to save System.Drawing.Rectangle object.

Comment: I mean that if your rectangle has minimum x-coordinate x0 and maximum x-coordinate x1, and similarly minimum y-coordinate y0 and maximum y-coordiate y1, then you store the rectangle as the point (x0,x1,y0,y1).  Then queries are as I described.

Answer (score 1):

This is a natural extension of a KD-tree.

When you have only points in your tree:

- Nodes in the tree correspond to regions of your space
- Given a parent node P and children nodes C1, C2, ..., CN, the children nodes Ci are mutually disjoint and they partition P
- Each point x is present in **exactly one** leaf node of the tree

When you have volumes in your tree:

- Nodes in the tree correspond to regions of your space
- Given a parent node P and children nodes C1, C2, ..., CN, the children nodes Ci are mutually disjoint and they partition P
- Each volume v is present in **at least one** leaf node of the tree (it's "in" any leaf node that it intersects with)

Comment: How should I check that rectangle is going to be on the left side or right side?

Comment: And how can I check that? I am checking x/y of current node and node to be added and adding it left or right.

Comment: I am following this http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc420-0401/pbasic.pdf